# navigation menu doesn't redirect to the given value

Tags: c#, redirect, navigation

the problem i encounted concerns redirecting in the navigation menu. I'd like to dynamicly create a navmenu. Depending on what role the user has we get to see the required navigation menu items.
At the moment i use:

```
if (found)
            {
                if (admin == true)
                {
                    NavigationMenu.Items.Add(new MenuItem("Agenda", "/AdminPages/Agenda.aspx"));
                    NavigationMenu.Items.Add(new MenuItem("Add Product", "/AdminPages/ProductToevoegen.aspx"));
                }
                else if (user == true)
                {}
```

This code I have placed in my Site.master.cs, but I also have a control in my login.aspx.cs code which does a `Response.Redirect("~/AdminPages/Agenda.aspx");` to a certain page depending on admin or user once logged in. Now the problem I have is that when I log in, a part works, so it controls the role and adds the required navigation menu items. But when I click for example on the Add Product link it doesn't redirect me to the page. It keeps redirecting me to :

```
http://localhost:52853/AdminPages/Agenda.aspx
```

In the url bar it actually shows the url followed with a # when clicked and than redirect to the Agenda page.

Any ideas on how to fix this problem? I tried finding a way to put the navigation links in the login.aspx.cs code aswell but couldn't find the correct way to refer to the NavigationMenu, don't know if that could be off any help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm might not be the correct way but i fixed it making another menu in the site.master.aspx file called MenuAdmin for example. Than in the code behind i've set the

```
NavigationMenu.visible = false;
```

and

```
MenuAdmin.visible = true;
```

Seems to work fine, does what it needs to do for now ;)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the parameters for creating a new MenuItem.

When only passing 2 parameters, you are filling the text and value parameters.  What you want to pass is a navigateUrl parameter.  This is only available when passing an imageURL parameter (which can be empty).

Something like the following should fix your problem.

```
NavigationMenu.Items.Add(new MenuItem("Agenda", "", "", "/AdminPages/Agenda.aspx"));
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a standard siteMap object and RoleProvider. And read a little bit about security trimming (you can specify on your sitemap nodes which roles can access which sites).

Comment: Yes I could do that, but isn't there a way to make this work?:)